# Object is not avaiable in current context

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass. // The name "myClass" Does not exist in the current context
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private void abc()
        { }
        public void xyz()
        { }

    }
}
```

Comment: `myClass` is a field belonging to `Program`, you can access it within in a method like `Main` but not outside of a method.

Comment: You have made `myClass` an instance field of the `Program` class. You won't be able to access it unless you are within an instance method of `Program`.

Comment: @JSteward - you would not be able to access it inside `Main` since `Main` is static and `myClass` is an instance field.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare myClass inside or outside of a method which will determine if it is a global instance or not, but you have to use it within a method, which in this case is probably going to be `Main`.

---

Edit: I was wrong. Since `Main` is a static method, you have to declare your instance of MyClass within `Main`. If you are using your instance of MyClass within a method that is not static, *then* you have the option of declaring it globally.

```
class Program
{
    MyClass myGlobalClass = new MyClass();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myLocalClass = new MyClass();
        //user the variable myLocalClass here
        //myGlobalClass will not work here because Main is static
    }
    private void NonStaticMethod()
    {
        //we can use myGlobalClass inside of this non-static method.
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private void abc()
    { }
    public void xyz()
    { }

}
```